# `Solve` with variables as single vector

Tags: equation-solving, vector

Say I have a set of equations where the unknown variables are the elements of a vector $c=(c_1,c_2,\ldots)$ and want to solve it for $c$. Is there a way to do this with `Solve` without typing out all the elements?

In other words: Instead of writing something like

```
Solve[{c1*x + c2*y == 1, -c1*x + 2*c2*y == -2}, {c1, c2}]
```

which works and gives

```
{{c1 -> 4/(3 x), c2 -> -(1/(3 y))}}
```

I'd like to write something like

```
Solve[{c[[1]]*x + c[[2]]*y == 1, -c[[1]]*x + 2*c[[2]]*y == -2}, c]
```

which doesn't work

Comment: What workflow do you have in mind, exactly?

Comment: Workflow? In my real computation I will solve much more complicated sets of equations where it would be nice to try different numbers of elements in $c$ without typing each element every time. Is that what you mean?

Comment: What I have in mind is that the solution I had in mind (which is similar to the ones offered, one of which you had accepted) saves very little effort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 cv = Array[ c , 2 ]
 Solve[
    { cv[[1]] x + cv[[2]] y == 1 ,  -cv[[1]] x  + 2 cv[[2]] y  == -2} , cv]
```

> {{c[1] -> 4/(3 x), c[2] -> -(1/(3 y))}}

```
 cv /. First@%
```

> {4/(3 x), -(1/(3 y))}

Answer (score 2):

And another completely different approach is to use LinearSolve

```
Clear[c1, c2, x, y]
eqs = {c1*x + c2*y == 1, -c1*x + 2*c2*y == -2};
vars = {c1, c2};
{b, mat} = CoefficientArrays[eqs, vars];
LinearSolve[mat, -b]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 1):

Another option:

```
vars = {c1, c2};
eqs = MapThread[{#1*x + #2*y == 1, -#1*x + 2*#2*y == -2} &, Map[List, vars]];
Solve[First@eqs, vars]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]